# InterSystems Cache class export

Tags: caching, export, intersystems

I am working with one project where I need to get the content of .cls file. I know how to get .xml file, however I need exact code which contains all comments and other stuff.
I found a class %Dictionary.ClassDefinition which can give a class name, properties. But is there any way to get raw class code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which version you use.

- 2014.1 and later - you may you class [%Compiler.UDL.TextServices](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20141/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?APP=1&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Compiler.UDL.TextServices), even this way may not work as expected.
- 2016.2 and later - you can just use $system.OBJ.ExportUDL()

In any versions earlier 2014.1, it still possible, but you can do it only by yourself by reading Class which stores in classes in package %Dictionary.